# How do i deal with this? trying to get the outcome to produce the names of the hostvars

Tags: python, ansible-inventory

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
Custom dynamic inventory script for ansible, in python
'''

# Importing modules needed
import os
import sys
import argparse

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

class ExampleInventory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {}
        self.read_cli_args()

        # Called with --list
        if self.arg.list:
            self.inventory = self.example_inventory()
        # Called with --host [hostname]
        elif self.arg.host:
            # Not implemented, since we return _meta info --list
            self.inventory = self.empty_inventory()
            # If no groups or vars are present, return an empty inventory 
        else:
            self.inventory = self.empty_inventory()

        print: json.dumps(self.inventory);

    # Example inventory for testing
    # This is hard coded, a more elegant one will probe an API which might be
```

provided by cloud providers
def example_inventory(self):
return {
"group": {
"hosts": [
"172.31.30.220"
"172.31.28.102"
"172.31.32.33"
"172.31.41.111"
],
"vars": {
"example_variable": "value"
}
},
"_meta":{
"hostvars": {
"172.31.30.220": {
"host_specific_vars": "web1"
},
"172.31.28.102": {
"host_specific_vars": "web2"
},
"172.31.32.33": {
"host_specific_vars": "db1"
},
"172.31.41.111": {
"host_specific_vars": "db2"
}
}
}
}

```
    # Empty inventory for testing:
    def empty_inventory(self):
        return {'_meta': {'hostvars': {}}}

    # Read the command line args passed to the script
    # Every inventory must provide this
    def read_cli_args(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--list', action = 'store_true')
        parser.add_argument('--hosts', action = 'store')
        self.args = parser.parse_args()

# Get the inventory.
ExampleInventory()


> Keep getting this error
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dynamic_inventory_example.py", line 84, in <module>
    ExampleInventory()
  File "dynamic_inventory_example.py", line 26, in __init__
    if self.arg.list:
AttributeError: 'ExampleInventory' object has no attribute 'arg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Used as `self.arg` but set as `self.args`. Use the same name in both places.